# Format all markers in Plotly with Python

Tags: python, plotly

I just started using `plotly` and I'm trying to format markers on my `plotly` pie chart based on the example [here](https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/).  When I do so, it only changes the marker formatting for one of the markers, not for all of them.  This appears to be the case in the example on the `plotly` website as well.  If you follow the link and look at the Styled Pie Chart, only Hydrogen has the white font, while all others have black font.

How can I make all of the markers have the same text formatting?

My code:

```
trace = go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, hoverinfo='label+value', textinfo='percent', 
           textfont=dict(size=20, color='#ffffff'),
           marker=dict(line=dict(color='#ffffff', width=2)))
```

Any help on how I can apply it to all markers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the format of hover info/hover label of a Pie chart in `Plotly` you would need to set the [`hoverlabel`](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#pie-hoverlabel) parameters.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
labels = ['Oxygen', 'Hydrogen', 'Carbon_Dioxide', 'Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]

trace = plotly.graph_objs.Pie(labels=labels, 
                              values=values,
                              textfont=dict(size=20),
                              hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor='black', 
                                              font=dict(color='white')
                                             )
                             )
plotly.offline.iplot([trace])
```

The snippet above would give hover labels with black background and a white font.

[image]

In your code `textfont` and `marker` specify the format of the labels inside the pie chart, not the hover labels. Plotly picks the colors for you if you don't specify them, it's just an accident that they match your color setting sometimes.